# Store code in folder separately to webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

The following scenario:

I have one folder where I have installed webpack, webpack dev server and all the dependiencies, as well as my webpack config.

Then I have another folder somewhere on my HDD (or another HDD) that contains the code I want to work with.

The problem is: I can provide the other folder to webpack-dev-server by using the "context" property, but I still want it to load node_modules from my folder where webpack is saved in.

For example I am unable to start the server with hot reloading, because he tells me he does not find the node module installed in the project sources folder :(

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - fixed it already. You simply have to provide full path names to your react modules and also define them as alias for the webpack-dev-server.